# Un .serialize() no me toma los datos del form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un problema con jQuery.

El problema es que tengo una petición AJAX para que me envíe dos datos a otra página .php que me hace una consulta.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var data=$("form").serialize();
        function obtener_modificacion(){
            $.ajax({                        
                type:"POST",                 
                url:"prueba2.php",
                success: function(data)             
                {
                    $('#consulta').html(data);               
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).on("click", "#buscar", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"prueba2.php",
                data:data,
                success: function(data){
                    obtener_modificacion();
                    alert(data);
                }
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

Y este es el formulario:

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="POST">
    <select name="tipodoc" id="tipodoc">
        <option value="0">Tipo de documento</option>
        <option value="T.I.">Tarjeta de identidad</option>
        <option value="C.C.">C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</option>
        <option value="C.E.">C&eacute;dula de extranjer&iacute;a</option>
    </select>
    <input type="number" name="documento" placeholder="N&uacute;mero de documento" id="documento" required>
    <input type="submit" name="buscar" value="Consultar" id="buscar"></input>
</form>
<section id="consulta"></section>
```

Así es la página .php que recibe los datos (prueba2.php):

```
<?php
require('conexion.php');
if (isset($_POST['documento']) && isset($_POST['tipodoc'])) {
    $doc=$_POST['documento'];
    $tipodoc=$_POST['tipodoc'];
    echo $tipodoc . " " . $doc . "<br>";
}
?>
```

Al querer enviar los datos, sí se generan las variables, pero sin valores; además, no me trae el echo del .php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Tu código está mal, aquí encuentro el origen de [la doble petición Ajax de tu otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/217959/29967) que te está trayendo problemas.

No es correcto lo que estás haciendo, llamar a una petición Ajax desde dentro de otra petición Ajax al mismo archivo. Esto no tendría ningún sentido. Te mostraré cómo hacer una sola petición:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#buscar" ).click(function( event ) {
            /*Con esto evitamos que se recargue la página*/
            event.preventDefault();
            /*Es más específico usar el id*/
            var data=$("#form").serialize();
            $.ajax({                        
                method:"POST",                 
                url:"prueba2.php",
                data: data,
                success: function(data)             
                {
                    $('#consulta').html(data);               
                }
            });
            })
    });
</script>
```

Haz lo mismo en el código de tu otra pregunta, simplificará el código y evitarás errores porque las peticiones Ajax son asíncronas.

Comment: Hermano... ¡Eres increíble! ¿Cómo hago para darte un puntaje, o algo así. Justo lo que necesitaba. Muchísimas gracias. Ya con todo lo que he aprendido, puedo por fin terminar mi página.

Por cierto, utilizar el id del formulario no me funcionó muy bien, pero es un detalle. 

Muchas gracias.

Comment: @SantiagoCorreaAguirreSanmar Por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda, ahí se explica lo que hay que hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que serializar los datos del *form* justo antes de enviarlos, en tu código lo haces solamente una vez cuando carga la página (`$(document).ready`)

```
    $(document).on("click", "#buscar", function(){

        var data = $("form").serialize(); // Agrega esta línea

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"prueba2.php",
            data:data,
            success: function(data){
                obtener_modificacion();
                alert(data);
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: ¡Perfecto! Sí me toma los datos. De hecho, voy aprendiendo más. Pero aún así, no me llama la página que necesito. ¿Puedes saber por qué? ._.

Comment: Tendría que adivinar, no veo otra cosa que esté mal.  En las herramientas de desarrollo del navegador (F12) ¿Ves que la llamada se ejecuta?, si se ejecuta, ¿es la URL que esperas?, ¿qué respuesta HTTP recibes, 200, 404?

Comment: Si te soy sincero, no entiendo qué me dijiste (pero sé cómo investigarlo).
Cuando envío los datos, me lo envía por GET (porque me aparece en la URL), ¿Será por eso que no me lo llama?