# Mi petición AJAX no se queda ahí

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ahora mi problema es que la petición se me envía, todo correcto; PHP7 me captura las variables y me hace la consulta, pero... Al momento de obtener los datos, la consulta no se me queda, si no que se me refresca toda la página de nuevo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function obtener_datos(){
            $.ajax({                        
                type:"POST",                 
                url:"consultar_aprendiz.php",
                success:function(data){
                    $('#consulta').html(data);  
                }
            });
        }
        $(document).on("click", "#consultar", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"consultar_aprendiz.php",
                data:$('form').serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    obtener_datos();
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

El alert(data) que está en el success, me muestra que la consulta sí se realiza, pero la página no se me muestra. Con otras pruebas, sí sé que la página se refresca y no que no la llama.

Quisiera saber porqué y si alguien me puede ayudar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien tu pregunta. Tampoco entiendo por qué tienes dos llamadas Ajax al mismo archivo.

Comment: Me refiero a que cuando le doy al botón con el id "consultar", sí me envía los datos y PHP me los recibe y hace la consulta que quiero, pero... El llamado a la consulta que se realiza en 'consultar_aprendices.php' no se mantiene en la misma página que se hizo la petición. O sea, esa página de inicio, se vuelve a cargar. 

La primera petición es para hacer el llamado y la segunda para enviar datos y activar la primera función.

Comment: Una llamada ajax que llama a otra llamada ajax y que a su vez se envían al mismo archivo.. no comprendo, podrías hacer todo en una. Además podrías poner tu código de ***consultar_aprendiz.php***, quizás nos ayude a comprender el problema.

Comment: ¿Me podrías decir cómo se hace en una sola función, por favor? Y ya actualizo la pregunta con el .php

Comment: estas reeescribiendo `$('#consulta').html(data);  ` por momentos con el codigo que tienes no te puedo ayudar no se lo que quieres exactamente, llamas al mismo servicio dos veces y reescribes

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo

Como no se sabe cómo está el resto del código,te pongo un ejemplo de como tendrías que poner la función AJAX de manera correcta,sin necesidad de llamar a otro método que haga otra consulta para que te lo pinte,por que ya se lo puedes indicar.En contentType,debes poner el formato de los datos que estás enviando a la página,y en el dataType,el tipo de datos que vas a recibir por parte de la página a la que consultas.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#consultar").on("click",function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            contentType:"application/json",
            dataType:"Json",
            url:"consultar_aprendiz.php",
            data:$('form').serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);
                 $('#consulta').html(data); 
            }
        });
    });
});
```